# How to use rules to store field value?

Tags: 7, entities, rules

I am writing a rule to store Tenant field's value to Previous tenant field whenever the Tenant field is updated and saved. The following are apartment and tenant content types.

Apartment content type:

- Room
- Tenant (entity reference to Tenant content type)
- Previous Tenant (unlimited number of values is set for this field)

Tenant content type:

- Name
- Phone

And this is my rule:

```
{ "rules_tenant_records" : {
"LABEL" : "Tenant records",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_update--apartment" : { "bundle" : "apartment" } },
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node-unchanged:field-tenant" ], "field" : "field_tenant" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "node:field-previous-tenant" ],
      "value" : { "value" : [ "[node:field-tenant]" ] }
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

It does not work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tenant:

[image]

#### Appartment:

[image]

#### Rule:

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

#### Rules Export:

```
{ "rules_store_tenant_name" : {
    "LABEL" : "Store Tenant Name",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : {
      "node_insert--appartment" : { "bundle" : "appartment" },
      "node_update--appartment" : { "bundle" : "appartment" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_fetch" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "node", "id" : [ "node:field-tenant:nid" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "list_add" : {
          "list" : [ "node:field-previous-tentant" ],
          "item" : "[entity-fetched:field-name] [entity-fetched:field-phone]",
          "unique" : "1",
          "pos" : "start"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works for me. Thank you so so so much. Is it possible to add you as a friend? :D

Comment: @Tony In your mind? Yes :) On this site? No, unfortunately, there is no such feature :(

Comment: Hi No Ssweat! When I add room, tenant and  previous tenant to Views, it lists everything. What I want is to show Room, which has current tenant and previous tenant. I have added to the filter criteria Content: previous tenant (not empty), but it makes a loop as if the room has 10 previous tenants, it shows 10 rows. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: @Tony please create a new question regarding this. Shows 10 rows of what? `What I want is to show Room, which has current tenant and previous tenant` just the last previous tenant (show only 1) OR you want to show all previous tenants?

Comment: Yes. I want to show all previous tenants, which i have already did. So in your example has 2 previous tenants and one current tenant. But the problem is if i have create a new Tenant which has name for example Jane and in Jane's room does not have any previous tenant, so how to hide Jane's room?

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps:

Instead of **Set data value** use **Add an item to a list** in action. In **List** field select `node:field-previous-tenant`, in **Item to add** field select `node-unchanged:field-tenant`. At last add an action **Save entity** and select `node` in Entity field.

Comment: I've upvoted this because you spotted the two mistakes and it's right but why the save entity?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried but it does not work, but @No Sssweat solution works for me